# Possible spam ring, but trying to describe it is too long for the custom moderator textbox

Tags: discussion, status-completed, spam, duplicate-accounts

I tried flagging a question and answer as needing moderator attention, but trying to describe the situation is simply too long for the textbox (over 200 characters too long), so I figured I would post it here instead.  If it was wrong of me to post it here, let me know.

---

There's something weird going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938473/monitoring-software-for-automatic-comparison-charts) with these users that's making my Spidey senses tingle.

All users in this question are relatively new users; Flora Williams asks for recommendations on 3/9, to which Clive Roger and Robert S. Wise both recommend [product redacted].  Flora responds to Clive wtih "thanks clive roger for your input, I never tried [product redacted]".

However, Flora Williams *answered* another post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28807787/334849) seven days *earlier*, saying "We are using [product redacted] for application performance monitoring."  I thought she just said she'd never used it before?

Then Clive goes and asks [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957749/tool-suggestion-for-specifically-monitoring-stats-for-locally-store-files), and there's Flora answering it, recommending something called [another product redacted].

My gut instinct tells me that this might be some sort of weird self-answering spam ring.

---

Could a moderator please look into this?

Comment: You did the right thing, bringing it here. If, of course, it turns out to be a spam ring

Comment: I have an elegant proof these users are spamming, but the proof is too long to fit in this comment box.

Comment: @Yakk -- I see what you did there

Comment: Nice catch Watson

Comment: @Yakk Great comment there ^^ I love it when I see little things like that around here and actually get the reference. :)

Comment: To report a _really_ long set of posts that might be a ring, put it on a private Gist and submit that. I've got rings closed down that way.

Comment: @halfer - can't tell if serious or not... >_>.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I see what you did there as well'); UPDATE Users SET Reputation = Reputation + 100 WHERE NAME = 'Flora';

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: serious! There were too many links that would fit into the custom field, so I had to send it on a pasteboard. Around 30 or so links, plus suspicious voting data.

Comment: @halfer - heh, that's pretty clever in that case

Comment: @ruffin - I'm pretty sure it was more of a `DELETE FROM Users` than `UPDATE Users` ;)

Comment: must... not... google... mindarray... What is that about "any press", again? An argument for *not* posting the question here, I think.

Comment: @shannon - I had thought about that, but decided that one Meta post wasn't going to make much of a difference, especially if it painted the product (or groups promoting it) in a bad light, but I went ahead and removed the product names just to err on the side of caution.

Comment: I was mostly kidding. Thanks for listening though.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Yup, spammers. Not the first time they tried this.

I destroyed these accounts and others that were associated with them (all promoting a group of products). They should be blocked from posting for a while, now that they've been fed into the anti-spam system.

Thanks for pointing this out. Even a little bit for us to go on in an "other" moderator flag is usually enough to get us to start pulling on a thread and unravel networks like this, so don't be afraid to use one of those even if you can't fit all details into it.

Comment: Awesome, good to know about the moderator flag, and thanks!

Comment: *if you can't fit all details into it* Sometimes I also reach the limit of the custom flags and then I try to short everything to the minimum. (Just a little extra question from my side: What should I do if I have the feeling that my flags doesn't get processed? e.g. One is still active since 27 feb)

Comment: @Rizier123 - That one flag you cast was about a handful of downvotes on your account, and I couldn't see an obvious pattern in them. However, I didn't want to dismiss it until someone else had a closer look, so I didn't clear the flag until someone could act on it. I should note that your 60 newer flags than that one were all processed quickly. A spam ring like this is easier to deal with than a few downvotes on a 10k+ account, so it can be acted on faster.

Comment: @BradLarson Okay thanks for the response. (Just noticed something else: I flagged this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22821921/3933332 As VLQ and it was declined, but the entire post got deleted, now was my flag wrong or was it declined, because the entire post got deleted and it was automatically declined?)

Comment: @Rizier123 - What happened there was that someone flagged every answer on that question as "not an answer", despite many being viable answers, and a moderator declined all those flags at once. Your flag came at just the same time, and was declined when those others were. It was an accidental casualty of that process. The question was the real problem, and that was dealt with.

Comment: @BradLarson Okay interesting what happened there, didn't knew that every answer was flagged as NAA. (So for the future when I see something like that should I better flag the Q instead of the answer?)

Comment: Cialdini has called this 'consumers from Mars'

Comment: @Rizier123 put the description on pastebin and link that in the flag